# working with character arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I have a string say, s1='hello', I want to manipulate it like an array, example in c++ we can use s1[i] to address the characters individually of this array, how do we do it in perl? I want to add the character at s1[0] with the character at s1[1]. I tried using

> ```
>   $s=join('',$s1[0],$s1[1]); 
>   $s=$s1[0].$s1[1];
>   $s=${s1[0]}.${s2[0]};
> ```

but am not able to concatenate the characters. I want to add h and e and put he, similarly e and l as el and so on, till the end of the word and then proceed the same with the next word.

can i also check like if s[i] is in list (b,c,d,h,l) and if s[i+1] is in (a,e,i,o,u) then add s[i] and s[i+1].

> Sample input:
>   hello 
>  disk 
>  caller
>
> Sample Output:
>   he l lo 
>   di s k
>   ca l le r

Comment: Can you explain what is your desired output from `hello hello`?

Comment: yes, i want to place b,c,d,h,l in a list and check if the s1[i] is in this list or not. S1 is a string. (am dealing with unicode strings)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to insert a space between two word characters as long as they are not in the two sets that you specified.

You can do this using `substr` like demonstrated by others, but this type of text manipulation is one thing that regular expressions were designed for:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/(?![bcdhl][aeiou])\w\K(?=\w)/ /g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
hello 
disk 
caller
```

Outputs:

```
he l lo
di s k
ca l le r
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this, using `substr()` to pick out individual characters:

```
perl -E '$s="hello";say substr($s,0,1),substr($s,4,1)'
```

Output:

```
ho
```

Answer (score 0):

[substr()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) is feasible:

```
print substr($s, $_, 1), " " for (0..length($s) - 1)
```

Output:

h e l l o

[substr()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) is also OK for inplace operations, as far it returns ref-value:

```
substr($s,0,2) = '';
say $s;
```

Output:

llo

Answer (score 0):

```
my @char_array = split "", $s1;
```

`@char_array` now contains all the characters of the `$s1` string and it's possible to manipulate it, iterate over it or do whatever to it just like with any other array.

Comment: Could you please add explanation to why this is good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can you `splice` to insert elements at a given position of the array:

```
echo -e 'hello\ndisk\ncaller' | perl -F'' -ane ' splice (@F,2,0," "); splice(@F,4,0," "); foreach(@F){print}'
he l lo
di s k
ca l ler
```

You can use Data::Dumper for better visualization when working with arrays:

```
echo -n 'hello' | perl -MData::Dumper -F'' -ane ' splice (@F,2,0," "); splice(@F,4,0," ");print Dumper(\@F)'
$VAR1 = [
          'h',
          'e',
          ' ',
          'l',
          ' ',
          'l',
          'o'
        ];
```